# Normalizr replacing SVG for PNG producing STRANGE results

Tags: css, svg

I'm using Normalizr to display alternate PNG background images, where SVG is being used, for older browsers.

**The no-svg class is being triggered, however, there are some strange results:** background sizing properties set on the backgrounds are lost on some elements, but seem to be retained on others. Furthermore, I couldn't use shorthand to set this (having to write separate declarations), but I imagine that's the browser's fault.

I need to control the sizing, especially because the layout is responsive.

If you have any ideas, please do reply.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: could you put a test case on something like codepen or jsbin..?

Comment: I'm not sure that will be of much help, the code is so simple (HTML is all semantic, the problem CSS is basic). Here's an example: .no-svg .play {
  background: black url("../img/play.png") center center no-repeat;
  background-size: 42%;
} I've been fiddling with it, IE 8 and below still no dice (read something about MS-specific filters), older Android fixed the problem by setting the problematic images' position to "contain". Why does a browser that doesn't' even support SVG, support "contain"? I have no idea.